# how to use select option value in html main body as variable in php sql statement same page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

As i understand PHP process from top to bottom that order. hence you have to define a variable before the statement using it.

But how would i make a select option value defined as a variable in my main body available for my statement above when the select value changes below should also change the scope automatically?

example.

```
    <?php

 // connect to MySQL
$conn1 = dbConnect('admin');

// prepare the SQL query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contract WHERE cont_num = '$contract_number'";

// submit the query and capture the result
$micko = $conn1->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

?>
```

my html, the variable contract_number is defined as a variable of the select options in the table below. how can i pass it back to the top for my sql statement. i also want the table to reload automatically when the select value changes as the variable value changes so it returns correct info. or if you have a better way i can do this please help.

```
<table>

<?php
while ($ayanda = $micko->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

<tr>
<select name = "contract_no">

<!--these select options are derived from a different sql statement as the rest of the  table-->

<?php
while ($row = $chuchu->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
<option><?php echo $row['cont_num']; ?></option>
<?php  $contract_number = '<option value="'.$row.'">'.$value.'</option>';?> 
<?php } ?>
</select>
<td></td>
<td><strong>Contruct Customer:</strong></td>
<td><?php echo $ayanda['cont_custm']; ?></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><strong>Account Number:</strong></td>
<td><?php echo $ayanda['accnt_num']; ?></td>
<td></td>
<td><strong>Contruct Volume:</strong></td>
<td><?php echo $ayanda['cont_vol']; ?></td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td><strong>Created:</strong></td>
<td><?php echo $ayanda['created']; ?></td>
<td></td>
<td><strong>Broker:</strong></td>
<td><?php echo $ayanda['broker']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: sounds like a job for jquery

Comment: use Ajax to both reload and use select option variable

Answer (score 0):

Because php is a server based script language, you have to do an asynchronus connection to the php file. You can do so with AJAX for example.

Load the php file with the selected value as get or post parameter. Then you can output the result of the sql statement in the php file and get this value in the ajax engine back.

Comment: is there a way of passing this value on the same page? if you have you php and html on same page? or it just has to be posted and captured as a $_POST['value'] on a different page?

Comment: you can do this on the same page but then you have to use an `if` statement arround your code, in which you check if the $_POST['value'] is set or not. But i would recommend to do this with an external page. It's a bit easier and clearer.